# is it possible to add Myriad pro font as like custom font face for web application in offline

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, typography, typekit

user needs Myriad Pro font in website, the website doesn't have internet connection to access the https://typekit.com/fonts/myriad?ctx=syncfont:6851.js  to access the font.

without adobe suite installation and typekit links provided in head tag of the 
page is there any other way to use the above as like other custom font.

is it possible to place the font in some folder in local like below

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that your webfont syntax is from 2012, not 2017 (just use woff/woff2. EOT and SVG don't *exist* anymore as font format, and TTF/OTF are full-spec system fonts), the answer should be pretty obvious: no of course not. If you had spent any time looking up the licensing options for Myriad Pro you would have found that Adobe only allows web deployment of this font through typekit. Also what does "the website doesn't have internet connection to access [...]" mean? It's the *user's* browser that loads that script and gets the font. Not the server.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably answer your question - it is an excerpt from [Typekit Font Licensing](https://helpx.adobe.com/typekit/using/font-licensing.html#web-app) page.

> **Can I use web fonts on my personal or company website?**
>   Yes. If your website is viewed in the browser–either on the desktop or on a mobile device–it's covered by the web font license.
>   The web font license also requires that the fonts be added to your website by the embed code that we provide. The [tutorial on adding fonts](https://helpx.adobe.com/typekit/using/add-fonts-website.html) to your website shows how it works.
>
> **Can I embed web fonts in a mobile or desktop application I’m building?**
>   No. Neither the sync font license or web font license allows you to embed the fonts within mobile or desktop applications. This requires an appropriate license to be purchased directly from the foundry or one of their authorized resellers.
>
> **Can I host the web font files on my own server?**
>   No. Typekit doesn't offer the ability to locally host fonts. Typekit web font hosting delivers fonts from a globally-distributed content delivery network (CDN), which performs much better and is more scalable than using local hosting for static assets.
>
> **Can I use web fonts for anything else?**
>   Probably not. The Typekit web font license requires that the fonts be added to a website with the embed code that we provide. If your website or web application is viewed in the browser–either on the desktop or on a mobile device–it's covered by the web font license.
>
> *If you have questions on any type of project not covered in this page, get in touch with the Typekit support team at support@typekit.com.*